# App Crashed due to Invalid signature for pointer dequeued from free list in UIImagePickerController

Tags: malloc, runtime-error, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8

I am facing problem in **UIImagePickerController** selection. When I choose source from Photo Library App crashes due to **Invalid signature for pointer dequeued from free list**. then If I run again it works fine with the same code. I searched on google and found one question related to my query [Xcode - My app crash and the error is "Invalid pointer dequeued from free list *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961954/xcode-my-app-crash-and-the-error-is-invalid-pointer-dequeued-from-free-list) .

but solution isn't working in my case.

I am using Xcode 8.1 and my deployment Target is 8.0.

Comment: Have you solved this issue/problem?

Comment: No,, it still crashing sometime... I think it is Xcode8.1 issue

Comment: I am also getting this exception right now and if i get any solution, I will surely answer you ASAP

Comment: @AnuragSharma did you find anything? Got the same issue

Comment: @luke ya i got this issue resolved by checking the authorisation first, then present the UIImagePickerViewController. I can post my code here if you want.

Comment: @AnuragSharma I actually thought I solved it but seems it's come back. Be great if you could

Comment: @luke please check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As @luke requested for the code for `UIImagePickerViewController`:

```
    let pickerView = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.allowsEditing = true

    pickerView.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    let authStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() // Get the current authorization state.
    // print(authStatus)


    if (authStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {

        // Access has not been determined.
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in

            if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                self.present(pickerView, animated: true, completion: { _ in })

            }

            else {

            }
        })

    } else if authStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
        print("Access has been granted.")

        self.present(pickerView, animated: true, completion: { _ in })

    }  else if (authStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
        print("Access has been denied.")

    }
    else if (authStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.restricted) {

        print("Restricted access - normally won't happen.")

    }
```

Now when the user picks a particular image:
This method will be called:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    //print(info)
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            YOUR_GLOBAL_IMAGE_VIEW?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            YOUR_GLOBAL_IMAGE_VIEW?.image = pickedImage

        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to import `PhotosUI` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks for this! The bug seems fairly random for me so will have to test it quite a few times over the next day or so.

Comment: Ok, no problem :)